# Swift struct return members

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have a struct like:

```
struct SectionInfo {
    enum AccountSectionInfo: Int, CaseIterable {
        case accountCreationDate
        case referredBy
        case referralCount
    }
    enum StatisticsSectionInfo: Int, CaseIterable {
        case tasksCompleted
             case pointsScored
    }
  // return AccountSectionInfo for index 0, for 1 return StatisticsSectionInfo
  func section(forIndex index: Int) -> XXX {}
}
```

I want to use it in a TableView like this:

```
cellForRow(at: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let section = SectionInfo.section(at: indexPath.section)
    if section == AccountInfoSection.rawValue {

    }
}
```

Is this possible in Swift?

Comment: If you *had* to do it, you would set the return type to be a protocol, to which both enums conform. But what exactly are you trying to achieve here? It's rather odd

Comment: @Alexander Well basically I want to have an index (indexPath.section) and I want to get a certain member (enum) of the structure based on the index (the rows enum)

Comment: Why not just add an enum property to the "TYPE" object?

Comment: @JanoschHübner Add a `func value(forSection:) -> SomeType` func to your object, that lets it respond with the correct value for the section.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah but SomeType? I need to access the cases of the return value

Answer (score 0):

> basically I want to have an index (indexPath.section) and I want to get a certain member (enum) of the structure based on the index (the rows enum)

So your struct is intended as the model for a table view data source? Then it's a very poor model. The natural way is like this:

```
struct Row {
    // properties needed to populate a row
}
struct Section {
    let title : String // or whatever else you need to populate section header
    var rows : [Row]
}
var model : [Section]
```

Now you can obtain a row as `model[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: The single case enum was just an example. Let it be any amount of cases

Comment: Then it wasn't a very good example, was it? Unless you show a meaningful use case, it's hard to help you. The Telepathy Manager is not working very well. Revise your question! As it stands, this is turning out to be an x-y problem. If this is supposed to be the data source for a table view, it is not how table view data sources typically work. Usually, they are an array of section structs each of which wraps an array representing the rows. A row is a row and an array is an array, so enums of multiple types don't come into the picture.

Comment: Rewrote my answer to show what a table view data model should look like.

Comment: I rewrote my question to show an example in table views

Comment: I just don’t want to check for indexPath.row == 0, indexPath.row == 1 etc.

Comment: And with an array you don't have to. Any time you find yourself checking for something by number, that's an array. An enum is not a natural match. Of course this could be an array _of enum cases_, and CaseIterable will give you that array for free in Swift 4.2.